# forloop TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, cisco, telnetlib

I am new to python3, trying to convert python 2.7 code to python 3, and I get into this issue. Let me know where I am wrong.

```py
for n in range (755,767):
    tn.write(b"vlan " + str(n) + "\n")
    tn.write(b"name Python_VLAN_" + str(n) + "\n")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./telnetlib_vlan_loop.py", line 30, in <module>
    tn.write(b"vlan " + str(n) + "\n")
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes**strong text**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error states: `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`

Your current issue is that you have `bytes` and `str` and you are trying to add them together. You need to use the same type prior to do so.

You are not providing if you need to write as `str` or `bytes`

If `bytes` change your code to:

```
for n in range (755,767): 
    tn.write("vlan {}\n".format(n).encode()) 
    tn.write("name Python_VLAN_{}\n".format(n).encode())
```

If `str` just remove the `encode`

```
for n in range (755,767): 
    tn.write("vlan {}\n".format(n)) 
    tn.write("name Python_VLAN_{}\n".format(n))
```

Update: fixed spelling of format

Comment: i think the trick was to encode the int  to byte. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

```py
for n in range(755,767):
    tn.write(b"vlan " + str(n).encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.write(b"name Python_VLAN_" + str(n).encode('ascii') + b"\n")
```

this might do the trick...hope it helps

Comment: Please edit your answer so that code appears as such. Also, post only answers that you have tested. A piece of code the "might do the trick" is not an answer. If you verified the code in your environment, but are unsure if the OP's environment will produce the same results, qualify your answer with the details of your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I handle with the same issue, and with code above fix that with .enconde('ascii') in both